# Using gtest with conan and cmake: 'test_properites_mutex_': undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, googletest, conan

I'm trying to use gtest (1.11.0) with conan, the test part of my CMakeFiles is like that:

```
# [...]

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

# [...]

# https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(MyProjectName test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyProjectName ${CONAN_LIBS})
add_test(NAME test COMMAND test)
```

And my test file is like that:

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(ApiTest, BasicTest) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

But when I compiles I have the following error:

```
\build\_deps\googletest-src\googletest\src/gtest.cc(2226,29): error C2065: 'test_properites_mutex_': undeclared identifier
```

Anyone would know how I could fix that?
I'm on Windows 10 using MSVC 19

Comment: You said you are using Conan, but I see `FetchContent_Declare`, so you are downloading GTest from Cmake. Also, you didn't share your conanfile and commands used to build. Remove the fetch content and use only Conan.

Comment: Smells like that you are building Gtest from the archive, but this build uses the headers from the Gtest installed by the Conan. As noted in the previous comment, do not mix two instances of the same project: either use Conan and remove FetchContent, or remove usage of the Conan.